# Can't override android color resources

Tags: android, android-color

I'm using this library https://github.com/savvisingh/DateRangePicker.
I would override default color of selected days, I declared these color resources:

```xml
<color name="calendar_selected_day_bg">@color/colorPrimary</color>
<color name="calendar_selected_range_bg">@color/colorPrimary</color>
<color name="dateTimeRangePickerStateToday">@color/colorPrimary</color>
```

The color of "Today" change correctly, but the color of selected days remains as default color(yellow), do you have any idea why it happens?

Comment: have you set the color programmatically or through xml?

Comment: You have to add the color code in the colors.xml in res -> colors.xml @Luca

Comment: I already declared the colors in colors.xml, but doesn't work

Comment: @sanjeev I set the color through colors.xml

Comment: No I asked if you have separately defined those colors in the `<com.savvi.rangedatepicker.CalendarPickerView` or programmatically in `ClassName.java` file

Comment: In neither, I can't found attributes or methods to set these colors  through xml or java object.

Answer (score 7):

Add override flag like bellow

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       tools:override="true"
```

to your color tag.

e.g.

```
<color name="calendar_selected_day_bg" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
           tools:override="true">@color/colorPrimary</color>
```